# Обособляется ли слово "честно"?

Tags: запятые, вводные-слова

### Мне(,) честно(,) всё равно.

Всё бы было хорошо, поставь слово "честно" в начале предложения, потому что в этом случае выделение неоспоримо, но что делать с похожим предложением, когда интонационно не отделяется, а запятые всё-таки поставить хочется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**МнЕ, честно, //всё равнО.**

Можно ли не обособить слово ***честно***? Давайте попробуем, **но в какой грамматической связи** оно будет находиться с другими словами? Ответ простой: **ни в какой**. Значит, не обособлять нельзя.

**А интонация?** Интонация ― это вещь непростая. Каждое предложение имеет собственную **(индивидуальную!)** интонационно-грамматическую структуру, и не всегда интонационное выделение вводного слова возможно. **Нет здесь общих интонационных правил для всех вводных слов, поэтому не стоит делать обобщающих выводов.**

В заданном предложении мы имеем встречу "короткого" местоимения и такого же "короткого" наречия в роли вводного слова. Поэтому небольшую паузу еще можно обозначить , но **сложно поставить два интонационных ударения подряд.**

Поэтому принцип постановки запятой **только грамматический.**

**Примеры:**

― Мне, **честно говоря**, неясно, что тут можно не понять, ― сказал Аполло. [Виктор Пелевин. Бэтман Аполло (2013)]

Мне, **честно,** плевать, как это называется ― был бы итоговый продукт. [Анатолий Кириллин. С собой не возьму // «Сибирские огни», 2012]

Скажи мне **честно.** Знаешь ведь, да? [Андрей Геласимов. Фокс Малдер похож на свинью (2001)]  (Наречие в роли обстоятельства).

Answer (score 5):

То, что вам удаётся переместить "честно" в начало предложения без изменения смысла, говорит о том, что это не член предложения, а *вводный* элемент. Это сокращение от более формальной вводной конструкции "честно говоря (если говорить честно)". По этой причине слово нужно обособлять запятыми, несмотря на то, что знаки явно противоречат интонации ("препинания" нет) - в правилах русской пунктуации это не отменяет предписанных знаков.

Comment: Получается, данное правило действует практически со всеми вводными словами? Мне, например, сейчас вспоминаются случаи, когда от позиции в предложении зависит обособление как раз таки из-за смены синтаксической роли.